# Trying to end a while loop once a 1 is randomly generated or it loops 10 times

Tags: c#, random, while-loop, terminate, sentinel

***(I apologize for the atrocious formatting)***

I am attempting to make a random number generator (min = 1, max = 10) that loops until either

**a) a 1 is generated (serve as primary sentinel).
b) loop iterates 10 times (secondary sentinel) without generating 1.**

I am looking for something like this:

*6 3 8 4 1
"A one was received in 5 attempts,"*

**or**

*3 8  5 7 2 2 4 8 8 3
"A one was never received."*

but the problem is that the loop continues even if a 1 is generated, and the "A one was never recieved." message displays.
The loop is as follows:

```
while (randomNumber.Next() != 1 || loopCounter <= 10));
{
    loopCounter++;
    Console.WriteLine(randomNumber.Next(10));
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    if (randomNumber.Next() == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"A one was recieved in {loopCounter} attempts.")
        break;
    }
    if (loopCounter <= 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A one was not recieved.")
        break;
    }
}
```

giving something like

*1 4 6 9 7 1 3 3 1 9 "A one was not recieved."*

Comment: The main problem here is that you call `randomNumber.Next()` three times for each iteration. Call it only once, and store the result in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You more or less had the right idea for deducting whether each of the two conditions were met (aside from the sleeping thread ?).

But if you do it after initialising variables to track what you were doing rather than checking as you go along it's easier to produce a method that meets the requirements for what I'm assuming is a homework question.

```
Random rand = new Random();
int randomNumber = 0;

int maxLoops = 10;
string numbersSoFar = "";

for (int i = 1; i <= maxLoops; i++)
{
    //Generate random number between 1 and 10:
    randomNumber = rand.Next(1, 10);
    numbersSoFar += randomNumber + " ";
    
    if (randomNumber == 1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numbersSoFar);
        Console.WriteLine("1 was found on loop number: " + i);
        break;
    }
    else if (i == 10)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(numbersSoFar);
        Console.WriteLine("10 loops completed, no 1 found.");
    } 
}
```

Since one of the conditions is that you have a maximum number of loops, you can use this in a `for loop`, rather than a while loop giving you access to an immediate `iterator` to compare against rather than declaring an extra value coupled with a while loop. This way it terminated automatically where as in your question you'd need a breakout/termination clause additionally for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue is that `Next()` returns a new random integer on each call, and without arguments returns any valid integer, so you have about a 1/(2^32) chance of getting 1.  Instead you should be calling it once on each iteration and reading that result a few times.  Your loop could look something like this:

```
List<int> nums = new List<int>();
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    nums.Add(randomNumber.Next(1, 10));
    if(nums.Last() == 1)
    {
        break;
    }
}
Console.Write(String.Join(" ", nums) + " "); 
if(nums.Last() == 1)
{
    Console.WriteLine("A 1 was received after " + nums.Length + " attempts");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("A 1 was not received.");
}
```